# PHP not loading SVG pattern textures

Tags: php, html, svg

I was messing around with some SVG and PHP codes, and I found a quite annoying problem which I can't solve.
I have an SVG image with some shapes in it. With the `fill` attribute and the `def` tag, I can successfully apply textures to the desired shapes with a simple GET variable. So this is my SVG:

[image: SVG image test]

And, if I want to apply any texture, I can see it perfectly:

[image: SVG with texture]

So, the problem is that, when I embed the image with an img tag, I can't see the texture.
I've configured a PHP file so, if I pass some values to the file, I can change the color and the texture. For example:

- **test.php?color=FF0000** will render my image with the red square
- **test.php?pat=pat1** will render my image with a pattern I have in a patterns folder

This works great if I wanna display the image, but, if I put it inside an `img` tag, it only works with the color, so:

- **`<img src="test.php?color=FF0000">`** will successfully render my image with a red square
- **`<img src="test.php?pat=pat1">`** won't render my texture; it displays the square with a white color

This is my `test.php` file (the PHP with the SVG code):

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/svg+xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
?>
<svg version="1.1" id="figure" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 612 345" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 345;" xml:space="preserve">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="100" height="100">
            <image xlink:href="img/patterns/<?=isset($_GET['pat']) ? $_GET['pat'] : 'pat1'?>.jpg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st1{fill:#62C3A9;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
    .st2{fill:#B8D433;stroke:#000000;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
    <rect fill="<?=isset($_GET['color']) ? '#' . $_GET['color'] : 'url(#img1)'?>" id="square" x="142.3" y="63" class="st0" width="125.3" height="167.3"/>
    <ellipse id="round" class="st1" cx="319.3" cy="134.7" rx="47" ry="53"/>
    <polygon id="polygon" class="st2" points="327,237.7 261.5,268.4 202.2,227.1 208.3,155 273.8,124.3 333.1,165.6 "/>
</svg>
```

What am I missing? I've been trying for an hour to find a solution but I haven't found anything useful yet.

[image: Preview on Chrome dev tools]

This is the preview I get on the Chrome dev console when I inspect the image, on the left with a color and on the right with a texture.

Thanks!

Comment: Then surely its the browser not PHP that is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you display SVG as an image i.e. via an  tag or as a background-image it must be complete in a single file i.e. no external references are allowed.

You'd have to convert the external image

```
xlink:href="img/patterns/<?=isset($_GET['pat']) ? $_GET['pat'] : 'pat1'?>.jpg"
```

into a [data URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) for this to work.

Comment: Yeah, that was it!! If anyone interested, I used this article in [how to convert image to data URI with PHP](https://paulund.co.uk/convert-image-base64-php). Thanks for your help, it worked like a charm!!